# Custom display of an object properties in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class

In MATLAB, I would like to customize an object such that one of its properties pertaining to data type would display a value (an original a numerical value corresponding to a code for a type) along with its string representation, something like: 'dobule' (14). In the code below, the property I am talking about is called `datatype`.

Currently, I have overridden `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` class and somehow sorted it out but I had to use a string variable to merge a number and a string and form a combined output. The problem is that MATLAB displays strings with quotations:

```Matlab
tidx = 
  idx with properties:

    dimensions: 3
      datatype: 'double (14)'
          size: [3 4 5]
```

This is fine but I don't like it. Is there any way that MATLAB would drop the quotation marks while it displays a string at this particular property?

Class definition:

```Matlab
classdef idx < matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay
    properties
        filename
    end

    properties(SetAccess=private)
        dimensions
        datatype
        size 
    end

% ...

    methods(Access=protected)
        function propgrp = getPropertyGroups(app)
            if ~isscalar(app)
                propgrp = ... 
                    getPropertyGroups@matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay(app);
            else
                sizestr = ...
                    sprintf('%s (%d)', app.datatypenum2str(app.datatype), app.datatype);
                propList = struct(...
                    'dimensions',app.dimensions,...
                    'datatype', sizestr, ...
                    'size',app.size);
                propgrp = matlab.mixin.util.PropertyGroup(propList);
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [overloading the disp method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/displaying-objects-in-the-command-window.html) for your class:

```
function str=disp(obj)
    p=properties(obj);
    for i=1:length(p),
        propval=get(obj,p);
        if isscalar(propval) % custom special format. 
        % Translation of original: sizestr = ...
                sprintf('%s (%d)', app.datatypenum2str(app.datatype), app.datatype);
            str{i}=sprintf('%s: %s (%d)',p{i}, datatypenum2str(propval), propval);
        else % standard display, mimicking getPropertyGroups@matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay
            str{i}=sprintf('%s: %s',p{i},disp(propval));
        end
    end
    str=sprintf('%s\n',str{:});

end
```

This way you can customize how a property is displayed at the root/ without using the matlab.mixin.util.PropertyGroup wrapper.

Comment: Your code is another way to solve this and I did think about overloading `disp`. I hoped I could leave MATLAB to format the output itself and sort out what to display and avoid the rest. Your code seem to reformat every property in an object it iterates through. I think it's easy to solve and needs just an extra `if` block, doesn't it?

Comment: I've tried to add the if block you wanted into my proposal ;-) See the if isscalar

Comment: Thanks. I am not certain if I follow so just in case I write this! My apology if I am wrong. What I meant was to apply my custom format to only one of the properties. I don't know what I am missing but I think your function in the current state iterates through all properties and apply the same format pattern to each scalar, in oppose to format pattern applied only to one selected property. Anyway thanks for help. It's a good start.

Comment: I've added some comments. HTH